# Winterizing exterior water lines from well

Tags: plumbing, well-pump, winterizing

I would like to extend the use of my water system into the winter months. Currently I shut off the water in late October and don’t reopen till early May. My well is 100 yds from my cabin. Water is drawn across a footbridge and the pipes are exposed, not buried, subject to freezing. Pressure tank is in an unheated shed approx 20 yds from the well and 80 yards from my cabin. Cabin is situated on a small island accessible via the footbridge. What I would like to do is winterize the current system without having to dig up existing water line run. What I have in mind is:

1. Build an insulated pump house on the camp side of the footbridge attached to an existing shed that
   currently has electricity and hosts the breaker switch for the pressure tank.
2. Move the pressure tank to the new pump house and run new water lines to the camp. Since the run between the new pump house and the camp will be about 10 yds I thought I might be able to use self regulating heat cable for in and out water runs to the camp.
3. Now for the big question. Would it be possible to rig a compressor between the pressure tank and run to the well to blow out the line after the tank has filled? Purging it of all water to prevent freeze up? Or is there another way to accomplish this.

All piping inside has been replaced with pex. Have both propane and a heat pump for interior heating. The outside 4" drain to the septic is covered by decking but I would most likely wrap with the self regulating heat cable as well.

Comment: Sounds complex. Complex things are prone to failure. I would suggest that you look into "inside the pipe" heating cable for the water supply side. Unless you have no room at all in the camp, put the pressure tank IN the building you are providing water to (cold climate SOP.)

Comment: For #3 will need a shutoff valve and a Tee with/added air nipple.  Probably manual use and get air in plumbing when ever turn pump back on.  Most of your ideas also depend on electric being on all the time, so good generator is also needed.  burying water lines is simplest unless bedrock at surface.  Have had -40 temps and lines never froze up underground.

Comment: Yes after looking into it further I’m thinking heat-lines regulated inline heat cable will do the trick. Generator is a must I agree.